# JavaScript instanceof: can't define what instance of function's argument is

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, instanceof, typeof

I'm still learning JavaScript,reading books,utilizing FireBug,experimenting.

I'm amazed and stuck on thing below.

Have function declaration:

```
    var t = function (args){
            ...
    }
```

It's assumed,that it's varargs.

I call it like:

```
<body onload="t({to:100,from:0})">
```

It's possible to get `from` argument value by calling:

```
args.from
```

The result of `typeof args.from` is `number`
That looks sane.
**pay attention:** `number` is in lower case

I am interested of what instance `args.from` is.
Actually, can't get its instance value.
tried:

```
args.from instanceof Number
args.from instanceof String
args.from instanceof Object
args.from instanceof Boolean
```

It is not `Number` - very strange
It's not `Object` - quite strange
It's not `String` -that's OK
 
It 's not `Boolean` -that's OK
 
It's neither `null` nor `'undefined'` - looks OK.

What is it?

Comment: BTW, that's not varargs; it's an ordinary parameter that happens to hold an object.

Comment: yes,I know, i wrote,that it's "assumed" varargs, opposite to Java,where it should be definitely declared

Comment: A value of the primitive Number type is not "an instance of" anything. The `instanceof` operator is used for Object values, not primitive values...

Comment: ... so, use `typeof` for primitive values, and `instanceof` for Object values...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a primitive numeric value.
It isn't an instance of any class.

`instanceof` can only return true on objects (for which `typeof` returns `"object"` or `"function"`).

This has nothing to do with the `args` *object*; you can get the same falsity from `4 instanceof Number`.

By contrast, `new Number(4)` is an object wrapping the primitive `4`, so `typeof new Number(4) === "object` and `new Number(4) instanceof Number === true`

Comment: oh,yes, i just realized,`number` lower case points on this also

Comment: A takeaway point from this is that you should not be doing strict type checking with `instanceof` everywhere a la Java. That's simply not the style of programming to which Javascript is suited. Use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and document expected arguments and interfaces.

Comment: @FrancisAvila- +1 for pointing out that strict typing in javascript is unreliable (and probably impossible in a general sense). Better to just test for the feature(s) needed or expected and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

As passed, `from.to` is a primitive type, so you can't call `instanceof` on it.

If you really want to use `instanceof` instead of `typeof`, wrap it in an `Object`:

```
var from = Object(args.from);
alert(from instanceof Number);   // true!
```

Comment: interesting thing: `typeof` results `object` in lowercase after wrapping.SLaks already explained it)

Comment: @sergionni yes, that's expected.

Comment: @Alnitak Your answer, in its current form, suggests an anti-pattern - wrapping primitive values in objects and then applying `instanceof` on them. The correct approach would be to not use the `instanceof` operator for primitive values, but to use `typeof` instead. I'm pointing this out, because in the future, some inexperienced programmer might see this answer and come to a false conclusion...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas text modified slightly.  One question though - what if you might also be expecting non-primitive values?  Wouldn't that be a case for converting to `Object` and then using `instanceof` ?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas now I'm understand,that it's primitive and I understand,that sometimes I need some Object properties to deal with,so need wrapping

Comment: @Alnitak What do you mean by non-primitive values? [Wrapper objects](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch03_12.htm) for primitive values (typed wrappers)? Or options/configuration objects (e.g. jQuery's [settings argument](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I mean what if a function could be passed a primitive _or_ different flavours of an object.  If you need to do run time checking of which flavour object it is, you need `instanceof`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas late Java has auto wrap/unwrap(so called boxing/autoboxing) and it's strictly typed language. JS is not strictly typed,but it doesn't have such a feature as I understand...

Comment: @Alnitak Let me first point out that wrapper objects are completely useless and and even considered dangerous (by Google and probably others). If the argument is coming from a third party, we would possibly have to guard against them (wrapper objects), but the assumption is (unless noted otherwise) that we control the input. Therefore, the function is not to expect wrapper objects. Now, if a settings/configuration object is one possibility for the argument, I would do this check: `if ( arg && typeof arg === 'object' ) { /* configuration object */ } else { /* primitive value */ }`.

Comment: @sergionni Yes, it does `:)` Try this: `'some string'.toUpperCase()` or `5..toFixed(2)`..